# How to slice a horizontal tail of a single line

Tags: linux, shell

given

file1

```
1:b:c:4
```

file2

```
1:3:47:8:aa:2
```

file3

```
1:4:5:8:9:11:aaaaa:2:3:4:88:9:10
```

I want to find the tail of this line after the ':'. To note each file only contains one line always

For example

```
$ command file1
4
$ command file2
2
$ command file3
10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/.*://' file*
```

The above `sed` command removes everything before the last `:` on each line (including the `:`).

Comment: Worked! Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F: '{print $NF}' file*
```

This awk command will print the last column (seperated by : (colon))

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash`:

```
line=$(<file)
echo "${line##*:}"
```

1. Read `file` into variable `line`.
2. `echo` the variable and remove the longest match (`##`) of prefix pattern `*:`

With `grep`:

```
grep -ho '[^:]*$' file*
```

You only need option `-o` (only print matched parts) if you have one input file. The `-h` suppresses printing of the filename before each match.